# Use sudo -i in bash script

Tags: bash, sudo

I would like to write a bash script to perform some tasks under root while logging as normal user. Is it possible to have something like this?

```
#!/usr/bash

sudo -i

<multiple line perform all my sudo command>
...
...
...
exit

<back to my user command, continue some other task>
```

Of course I can put a sudo every line, but I would like to find out is it possible to do something like above? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about something simple like this.

```
#!/usr/bash
sudo bash << EOF
# Everything until EOF is run in a sub-shell
echo 'Hello World'
whoami
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler approach:

```
#!/usr/bash

sudo sh another_script.sh

<continue some other task>
```

Here is the other script.

```
#!/usr/bash
<multiple line perform all my sudo command>
...
...
...
```

If you want to avoid prefixing each command with `sudo`, you can just include them in another script and call it.

Comment: This will work, but you don't really need a separate file, just a sub-shell.